# Automapper to read single record

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have been trying to read single Record using AutoMapper. But I couldn't get through using the below code,

```
    public ChartOfAccount GetSingleCOA( )
    {

        string queryString = "select * from ChartofAccounts where AccNo=423";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    return Mapper.Map<IDataRecord, ChartOfAccount>(reader);
                }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use some ORM like `Dapper` or `Entity Framework`

Comment: trying to use AutoMapper here.Can read list easily , but want to restrict single record(object ) here

Comment: Mapping part needs to done in mapper profile isn't it?

Comment: Simply to read all the columns of sql record to Object of class, one can easily read list using code :  Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<T>>(reader);  without doing any specific mapping . But here I just want to get single object not list

Answer (score 1):

simply changing the line to

```
 return Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, ChartOfAccount>(reader);
```

solved the issue